# Django - values_list CSV

Tags: django, csv, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I'm trying to export `CSV in Django` and using `values_list` to select field i want to export.

**`My First Try`**

```
class ExportCSV(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        incidents = Incident.objects.filter(
            interview_date__range=(start, end),
            partner__twg=self.request.query_params.get("twg"),
        )

        for incident in incidents:
            writer.writerow(
                [
                    incident.incidenttwg1.getchild.values_list(  # <-- This line
                        "choice", flat=True
                    )
                ]
            )
```

I got this. `<QuerySet ['Hello', 'Gudbye']>`, so i decide to create `loop` to fetch `Hello and Gudbye`.

**`Here my second Try`**

```
class ExportCSV(APIView):
    def getincident(self, request, incident):  # Create a function
        for incident in incident.incidenttwg1.getchild.values_list("choice", flat=True):
            return incident

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        incidents = Incident.objects.filter(
            interview_date__range=(start, end),
            partner__twg=self.request.query_params.get("twg"),
        )

        for incident in incidents:
            writer.writerow([self.getincident(request, incident)])  # Call function
```

I create a `getincident` function to make it `cleanable` to read.

what i got is `Hello`, its suppose to be `Hello` and `Gudbye` not only `Hello`.

Any Help?? Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're taking about the function `getincident`?

You are only getting the first value because of of the `return` statement location.

```
def getincident(self, request, incident): # Create a function
    return [incident for incident in incident.incidenttwg1.getchild.values_list('choice', flat=True)]
```

this should give you all the values, in a list.

Comment: i try use `yield` but got this `<generator object  at 0x7f00ccf56ba0>`

Comment: You're right, going over your origin code again, I would use the 2second option.  I'll remove the yield approach.